# Use Index as a variable for an equation in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have the following code:

```
def linear_rank_selection(popRanked):   
selectionResults = []
n = len(popRanked)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(popRanked), columns=["A","B"])
df['Probability'] = 2*(n- df.index+1 )/(n*(n-1))*100
```

How can I use the index number, as a variable, to create the Probability column? Based on the [probability formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpJkm.png) whereas j is the index number.

Comment: what is popRanked?

Comment: Its a 2d np.array (something like that : PopRanked [(100, 50), (215, 3) , (500,4)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is with `RangeIndex` when we try to do the division. Try convert index to numpy:

```
popRanked = [(100, 50), (215, 3) , (500,4)]
n = len(popRanked)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(popRanked), columns=["A","B"])
df['Probability'] = 2*(n- df.index.to_numpy()+1 )/(n*(n-1))*100

print(df)
     A   B  Probability
0  100  50   133.333333
1  215   3   100.000000
2  500   4    66.666667
```

We can also use `df.index.values` instead `df.index.to_numpy()`